# How do you use the PHP OpenPGP library?

Tags: php, gnupg, openpgp

There is a [PHP extension port](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.gnupg.php) of the [gnupg](http://www.gnupg.org/) PGP library. However, I'm having a hard time [finding examples](http://www.php.net/manual/en/gnupg.examples-clearsign.php) that explain how to use the library.

How do you properly create keys for application users, and then use them to encrypt/decrypt text using the GnuPG library?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

See this URL it is very help full to you. Download example and try it.

https://github.com/singpolyma/openpgp-php

**Or Try it:-**

You can download **lib/openpgp.php** and **lib/openpgp_crypt_rsa.php** files in above the URL.

**examples/keygen.php**

```
<?php

require dirname(__FILE__).'/../lib/openpgp.php';
require dirname(__FILE__).'/../lib/openpgp_crypt_rsa.php';

$rsa = new Crypt_RSA();
$k = $rsa->createKey(512);
$rsa->loadKey($k['privatekey']);

$nkey = new OpenPGP_SecretKeyPacket(array(
   'n' => $rsa->modulus->toBytes(),
   'e' => $rsa->publicExponent->toBytes(),
   'd' => $rsa->exponent->toBytes(),
   'p' => $rsa->primes[1]->toBytes(),
   'q' => $rsa->primes[2]->toBytes(),
   'u' => $rsa->coefficients[2]->toBytes()
));

$uid = new OpenPGP_UserIDPacket('Test <test@example.com>');

$wkey = new OpenPGP_Crypt_RSA($nkey);
$m = $wkey->sign_key_userid(array($nkey, $uid));

print $m->to_bytes();
```

**examples/sign.php**

```
<?php

require dirname(__FILE__).'/../lib/openpgp.php';
require dirname(__FILE__).'/../lib/openpgp_crypt_rsa.php';

/* Parse secret key from STDIN, the key must not be password protected */
$wkey = OpenPGP_Message::parse(file_get_contents('php://stdin'));
$wkey = $wkey[0];

/* Create a new literal data packet */
$data = new OpenPGP_LiteralDataPacket('This is text.', array('format' => 'u', 'filename' => 'stuff.txt'));

/* Create a signer from the key */
$sign = new OpenPGP_Crypt_RSA($wkey);

/* The message is the signed data packet */
$m = $sign->sign($data);

/* Output the raw message bytes to STDOUT */
echo $m->to_bytes();

?>
```

**examples/verify.php**

```
<?php

require dirname(__FILE__).'/../lib/openpgp.php';
require dirname(__FILE__).'/../lib/openpgp_crypt_rsa.php';

/* Parse public key from STDIN */
$wkey = OpenPGP_Message::parse(file_get_contents('php://stdin'));
$wkey = $wkey[0];

/* Parse signed message from file named "t" */
$m = OpenPGP_Message::parse(file_get_contents('t'));

/* Create a verifier for the key */
$verify = new OpenPGP_Crypt_RSA($wkey);

/* Dump verification information to STDOUT */
var_dump($verify->verify($m));

?>
```

Comment: Doing encryption with a random PHP library found on the net, which reimplements PGP from scratch, with none of the authors being a cryptographer, and the library apparently a work in progress (half the functions have a single `//TODO` as their body). What could go wrong?

Comment: @Tgr "The ultimate ignorance is rejection of something you know nothing about yet refuse to investigate." The only thing that could be dangerous about this is the call to `createKey()`, which comes from https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib/blob/master/phpseclib/Crypt/RSA.php#L576, which calls, what was that? OpenSSL. OpenSSL is now a "random PHP library found on the net"? Please do some research before writing comments like these.

Comment: @8chan, key generation is actually not the only part of crypto that can contain dangerous mistakes - encryption can too (I would think that obvious). Also, phpseclib (which, unlike openpgp-php, did get some amount of scrutiny, although [not nearly as much as OpenSSL](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/44581/is-phpseclib-a-secure-and-reliable-alternative-to-openssl)) does it's own key generation if OpenSSL is not available, and reimplements the actualy encryption in pure PHP. And even when you have a safe cryptographic primitive, you can apply it in insecure ways.

Comment: I am getting the error. Fatal error: Call to a member function equals() on a non-object in /www/openpgp-php-master/vendor/phpseclib/phpseclib/phpseclib/Crypt/RSA.php on line 2091. Any idea?

Comment: you can download "phpseclib" lib from composer in your vendor folder.

Comment: How do you use this library if you download it using composer require singpolyma/openpgp-php ?

Comment: This is such a bad library. Almost none of the source code is properly documented and you have to work everything out for yourself, or rely on couple of similarly useless undocumented examples and hope you don't run into any problems. Also it's unnecessarily overcomplicated.

Answer (score 7):

They are very good examples based on [PHP extension port](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.gnupg.php)  has you have requested and we would take a look at some examples

[Using GnuPG with PHP -- Full Tutorials](http://devzone.zend.com/1278/using-gnupg-with-php/)

### Example

#### Getting Key Information

```
putenv('GNUPGHOME=/home/sender/.gnupg');

// create new GnuPG object
$gpg = new gnupg();

// throw exception if error occurs
$gpg->seterrormode(gnupg::ERROR_EXCEPTION); 

// get list of keys containing string 'example'
try {
  $keys = $gpg->keyinfo('example');
  print_r($info);
} catch (Exception $e) {
  echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

#### Encrypt a Simple Mail

```
// set path to keyring directory
// set path to keyring directory
putenv('GNUPGHOME=/home/sender/.gnupg');

// create new GnuPG object
$gpg = new gnupg();

// throw exception if error occurs
$gpg->seterrormode(gnupg::ERROR_EXCEPTION); 

// recipient's email address
$recipient = 'dgar@example.org';

// plaintext message
$plaintext = 
"Dear Dave,\n
  The answer is 42.\n
John";

// find key matching email address
// encrypt plaintext message
// display and also write to file
try {
  $gpg->addencryptkey($recipient);
  $ciphertext = $gpg->encrypt($plaintext);
  echo '<pre>' . $ciphertext . '</pre>';
  file_put_contents('/tmp/ciphertext.gpg', $ciphertext);
} catch (Exception $e) {
  die('ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage());
}
```

#### Decryption The Mail

```
// set path to keyring directory
putenv('GNUPGHOME=/home/recipient/.gnupg');

// create new GnuPG object
$gpg = new gnupg();

// throw exception if error occurs
$gpg->seterrormode(gnupg::ERROR_EXCEPTION); 

// recipient's email address
$recipient = 'dgar@example.org';

// ciphertext message
$ciphertext = file_get_contents('/tmp/ciphertext.gpg');

// register secret key by providing passphrase
// decrypt ciphertext with secret key
// display plaintext message
try {
  $gpg->adddecryptkey($recipient, 'guessme');
  $plaintext = $gpg->decrypt($ciphertext);
  echo '<pre>' . $plaintext . '</pre>';
} catch (Exception $e) {
  die('ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage());
}
```

You should also look at the Example

- http://www.developertutorials.com/pear-manual/package.encryption.crypt-gpg.examples.html
- http://oregonstate.edu/cws/docs/gpgwrap
- http://www.phpclasses.org/package/1724-PHP-Encrypt-data-and-manipulate-keys-using-gnuPG.html