# Facing issues with using Openpgp library

Tags: openpgp

I downloaded the [OpenPGP example code](https://github.com/singpolyma/openpgp-php) mentioned in question [How do you use the PHP OpenPGP library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12411738/how-do-you-use-the-php-openpgp-library).

I faced following error when I tried to access `keygen.php`:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method OpenPGP_Message::signature_and_data() in D:\official\data\sites\openpgp\lib\openpgp_crypt_rsa.php on line 145

Infact, none of three is working. Can you please explain how to fix these issues?

Answer (score 0):

I guess that line 148 in https://github.com/singpolyma/openpgp-php/blob/master/lib/openpgp_crypt_rsa.php

must be corrected from:
$sig = $packet->signature_and_data();

to:
$sig = $packet->signatures();