# Examples of using PHP GnuPG

Tags: php, gnupg

Are there some solid examples of using this extension? What I found so far in searching is very sketchy and makes assumptions that you are already familiar with all of the functions and how they work. Specifically I am trying to figure out how you come up with the $fingerprint parameter that is used in many of the functions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Encrypt files using PGP in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15969740/encrypt-files-using-pgp-in-php)

Comment: maybe useful? [How do you use the PHP OpenPGP library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12411738/how-do-you-use-the-php-openpgp-library)